# What is the difference between req_extensions in config and -extensions on command line?

Tags: openssl, x509, csr, pkcs#10

The sample openssl root ca config from the [OpenSSL Cookbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/openssl-cookbook/) defines the following (p40):

```
[req]
...
req_extensions = ca_ext

[ca_ext]
...
```

Later (p43), the root ca key is generated, then the root ca selfsigned cert.

```
openssl req -new \
-config root-ca.conf \
-out root-ca.csr \
-keyout private/root-ca.key

openssl ca -selfsign \
-config root-ca.conf \
-in root-ca.csr \
-out root-ca.crt \
-extensions ca_ext
```

Isn't req_extensions redundant in this specific use case? 
When is req_extension really needed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 6):

`req_extensions` is used for declaring *request extensions* to be included in PKCS #10 *certificate signing request* (CSR) objects.  The extensions are part of the signed data in the CSR.
In general, a CA, when creating and signing a X.509 certificate in response to a CSR, and depending on the certificate profile, may or may not heed particular request extensions.  You will need to use this to generate a CSR for use with a CA that expects particular information to be conveyed in this way.

OpenSSL itself does not copy *any* extensions from PKCS #10 requests to X.509 certificates; all extensions for certificates must be explicitly declared.  The OpenSSL [`x509` man page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:X509(1)#BUGS) provides some commentary:

> Extensions in certificates are not transferred to certificate requests and vice versa.

Because you are using the OpenSSL CA, the use of `req_extensions` is indeed redundant.

Comment: `x509 -req` does not copy extensions from the CSR, but `ca` does if and only if `copy_extensions` is set in the config; see the man page for `ca`

Answer (score 0):

"req_extensions" corresponds to the -reqexts command line switch.

"x509_extensions" corresponds to the -extensions command line switch.