# Invalid CA certificate with self signed certificate chain

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a self signed certificate chain with these commands and configured them on an Apache server

But when i try `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect my-host.local:443 -CAfile all.crt`

I get an error from openssl `Verify return code: 24 (invalid CA certificate)`

Is there something wrong with the commands used to generate the certificates or with the configuration files?

### commands used to create certificate chain

```
# self signed root cert
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3000 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -config ca.conf

# intermediate cert signed with the root cert
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out int.key 4096
openssl req -new -key int.key -out int.csr -config int.conf
openssl x509 -req -days 3000 -in int.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out int.crt

# leaf cert signed with the intermediate cert

openssl genrsa -aes256 -out leaf.key 4096
openssl req -new -key leaf.key -out leaf.csr -config leaf.conf
openssl x509 -req -days 3000 -in leaf.csr -CA int.crt -CAkey int.key -set_serial 01 -out leaf.crt

 cat ca.crt int.crt leaf.crt > all.crt
```

### These are the config files I have used

> #### ca.conf
>
> [ req ]
> distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name
> x509_extensions        = v3_ca
> dirstring_type = nobmp
> [ req_distinguished_name ]
> commonName                     = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
> commonName_default             = root
> [ v3_ca ]
> keyUsage=critical, keyCertSign
> subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
> authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
> basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE,pathlen:1
> extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth
>
> #### int.conf
>
> [ req ]
> distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name
> x509_extensions        = ext
> [ req_distinguished_name ]
> commonName                     = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
> commonName_default             = int
> [ ext ]
> keyUsage=critical, keyCertSign
> subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
> authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
> basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:0
> extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth
>
> #### leaf.conf
>
> [ req ]
> distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name
> dirstring_type = nobmp
> [ req_distinguished_name ]
> commonName                     = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
> commonName_default             = leaf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A CA root certificate [has to be marked as belonging to a CA](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html):

> A CA certificate **must** include the basicConstraints value with the CA
>   field set to TRUE. An end user certificate must either set CA to FALSE
>   or exclude the extension entirely. Some software may require the
>   inclusion of basicConstraints with CA set to FALSE for end entity
>   certificates.

This is done through the *basic constraints* standard extension. To check whether your root cert has the `CA` attribute set, run `openssl x509 -text -noout -in ca.crt` and look for `CA:True` in the output. Note that OpenSSL will actually [let you sign other certs with a non-CA root cert](https://superuser.com/a/464288/778853) (or at least used to) but verification of such certs will fail (because the CA check will fail).

With your config file, simply including `-extensions v3_ca` in the command to generate the root cert should suffice:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -days 3000 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -config ca.conf -extfile ca.conf
```

Comment: Is `x509_extensions = v3_ca` in ca.conf different from `-extensions v3_ca`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274766/what-is-the-difference-between-req-extensions-in-config-and-extensions-on-comma