# Verification of a certificate chain fails on the leaf certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, pyopenssl

I produced a PEM certificate chain (CA, intermediate and leaf) using `pyopenssl`, and I wanted to confirm that I defined everything properly.

Here are the steps I took:

1. I made the three PEM certificates, self signed the CA and defined the basic constraint `crypto.X509Extension(b'basicConstraints', False, b'CA:TRUE')` following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951346)
2. I copied the CA and intermediate certificates to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` (as crt files) and ran `sudo update-ca-cert`
3. I've set up a simple server based on [this OpenSSL example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server)
4. I tried running the server with the CA certificate and executed `openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs` - Worked great, got `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`
5. Did the same thing but this time the server used the intermediate certificate - Also great, `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`
6. Did the same thing but this time the server used the leaf certificate - This time I got `Verify return code: 24 (invalid CA certificate)`

In addition, I tried verifying the certificates and got the following:

```
$ openssl verify 1-ca.pem
1-ca.pem: OK
$ openssl verify 2-intermediate.pem
2-intermediate.pem: OK
$ openssl verify 3-leaf.pem
C = NL, ST = Amsterdam, L = Zaandam, O = FakeDigiCert, OU = FakeFake, CN = www.fakedigicert.nl
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error 3-leaf.pem: verification failed
```

Why is the CA certificate suddenly invalid once the server's certificate is more than one step away from the CA?

Comment: You don't make clear exactly what you put in which cert, but you say 'CA and intermediate' as if the intermediate were not a CA, which it is. What you have is a root CA, one intermediate CA, and an end-entity aka leaf. OpenSSL requires the/each intermediate CA has BasicConstraints.ca=true otherwise you get verify error 24; at least as of now it doesn't require this for the root CA unless the code sets a 'strict' flag, but a root _should_ have it nevertheless.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That was indeed the issue. I assumed that an intermediate certificate isn't necessarily a CA. Once I added the basic constraint, the verification passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common trap most people fall into setting up https web server do all the time.  You need to provide the all intermediate certificates to the web server as well (normally by combining the leaf and intermediate pem files into one pem file). So when web browsers go to your site, the SSL setup should return both the leaf and the intermediate certificates from the web server.

You can see this on all web sites that provide intermediate certificates when you use the -showcerts option with the opensll [s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_client.html) command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -showcerts
```

The same is true for the openssl [verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-verify.html) command as well.

From the docs:

> -untrusted file
>
> A file of additional untrusted certificates (intermediate issuer CAs) used to construct a certificate chain from the subject
> certificate to a trust-anchor. The file should contain one or more
> certificates in PEM format. This option can be specified more than
> once to include untrusted certificates from multiple files.

So in your example above you need to do:

```
openssl verify 3-leaf.pem -untrusted 2-intermediate.pem
```

Comment: Omitting the intermediate is indeed a common mistake, but it CANNOT cause the specific error shown in this Q.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Would that mean that the leaf certificate is setup with 'CA:TRUE' when it shouldn't?

Comment: @ShanePowell It seems that dave_thompson_085's solution solved the issue, however I'd appreciate clarification on what you said. If I install the the root certificate on my client's host, and then provide a chained file containing all three certificates, s_client's check should be fine? Because when I uninstalled the intermediate certificate, I got "Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)"

Comment: @GabeL: per standard an SSL/TLS server should send the whole chain except that it _may_ omit the (nontrivial) root; in your case it should send at least leaf and imed. Most servers send what you configure (only), but some vary. If the server wrongly sends only the leaf, what the client does is not specified by standard; `openssl s_client` in particular, if you have both root and imed in its truststore (`-CAfile` and/or `-CApath` or their defaults), uses imed from the truststore to build the chain, and validation will succeed (if/once the certs are correct).

Comment: Shane: no. As I commented on the Q, what causes verify 24 is an _intermediate_ that _lacks_ ca=true. OpenSSL accepts a 'leaf' with ca=true -- including but not limited to a self-signed cert where the leaf is also the root and must be directly trusted.